# Apple Match O linker error

Tags: ios, debugging, ios7, linker-errors

I am getting an Apple Match  O linker error and I really don't know where I made a mistake . I really need  help. Thank you.

Please feel free to download my project from http://wikisend.com/download/690420/Couturier 2.zip

Answer (score 1):

Compiler shows duplicate symbol error.. When I looked in to your code I see more than 1 implementations of

```
  Ld /Users/rajesh-2497/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Couturier-hjowwgfpdkptpogvpvydyrxctoaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Couturier.app/Couturier normal x86_64
    cd /Users/rajesh-2497/Downloads/Couturier
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    /Users/rajesh-2497/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Couturier-hjowwgfpdkptpogvpvydyrxctoaw/Build/Intermediates/Couturier.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Couturier.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ShoesViewController.o
ld: 26 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

this many classes remove duplicate implementations and build your application

[image]

Comment: It still does the same thing even though I changed the code.

Comment: it has number of duplicate files